# Can I export a list of WooCommerce product category URLs from WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to export a list of URLs from our WordPress / WooCommerce website that includes the product category URLs (not individual product URLs or other pages). Is this possible? I'm running the latest versions of WordPress and WooCommerce.

I tried a WordPress plugin called "Export all URLs" which exported a list of URLs for product pages, but not for their parent categories.  The category URLs are what I need.

Our shop has thousands of products and hundreds of categories, so manually copying the URLs from the shop is not a great solution.

If the best solution is php, that is not something I am familiar with and could use guidance. I am a front-end WordPress designer, but am not a php guy.